# Metadata / Exif editor for Mac OS X w/ GUI

Tags: gratis, osx, images, metadata-editor, exif

I've been searching for a free Mac OS X image exif / metadata editing tool, with a GUI, but didn't find any.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. E.g. what features do you need, what budget you are willing to invest if needed (or whether the software needs to come free of charge), whether it has to be a native OSX solution (or web-apps are acceptable as well).

Comment: i'll be back in a few hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did find a python/pySide Qt4 tool called [pyExofToolGUI](https://github.com/hvdwolf/pyExifToolGUI) *by hvdwolf* which **should** work on OS-X, *not having a Mac I can't be 100% sure*, I did find that for Windows 10 a little work was needed to get it running and will be posting my changes up later if anybody is interested.

- Free Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform
- Thumbnail display
- Looks to give access to most, *if not all*, of the ExifTool functionality
- Displays the readable data from supported formats
- Can bulk edit of *some* writable data
- You can add your own ExifTool commands

### View Data

[image: View Data]

### Edit GPS Block

[image: Edit GPS Block]

### Edit Exif Block

[image: Edit Exif Block]

*The above screenshots were taken on Windows 10 after a few tweeks to get it running, using Python 2.7.11 - I was unable to test under Python 3 as my current installation is Python 3.5.1 and PySide does not **at the time of writing** support > Python 3.4.x*

*For any windows users having issues I have committed the changes that it took to get things working for me, (Windows 10 Python 2.7.11), to https://github.com/GadgetSteve/pyExifToolGUI and have raised a pull request on the original.* ***Update*** - *Pull request has been accepted.*

Comment: yep, working with it from day one, it has a bug that it doesn't find the config file, but you can start it from a terminal with the config file as an argument and it works just fine.